# CSS/JS addClass works in development (Rails) but not in heroku

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript

Any idea why this works in development, but not when deployed on heroku:

```
    if $('#home-header').data('votable') == true
        $('#mpimage1').addClass('mpimage')
        $('#mpimage2').addClass('mpimage')
    else
        $('#mpimage1').removeClass('mpimage')
        $('#mpimage2').removeClass('mpimage')
```

The CSS:

```
.mpimage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  &:active {
    top: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 3px #ccd2d2, 0 7px 20px 6px #d5dbdb;
  }
}
```

I need to do this because `<div id="mpimage1">` and `<div id="mpimage2">` are within a partial, and they are clickable when used on one page containing the partial, and they are not clickable on another page that uses the partial. I only want the `:active` effect to come into play when it is clickable. Thanks!

Comment: Where is that code? When does it run?

Comment: @muistooshort, the Coffeescript is in /home.js.coffee and the CSS is in custom.css.scss.

Comment: Is the code wrapped in a `$(document).ready ->` wrapper or similar? Does the code run at all?

Comment: Yes, I am using Coffeescript and the code begins with `jQuery ->`. It runs without a problem in my local environment, and the rest of the file (just not the add/removeClass portion) runs without issue when deployed.

Answer (score 1):

If your code works on dev but not on heroku, then it's most likely not a problem with your code.  I would start by looking at the Javascript console when viewing the site on heroku.  You may see errors there.

Perhaps a gem that works locally is acting differently on heroku.  Are you sure that there weren't any errors when pushing to heroku?

Any thing in your heroku logs?  (type 'heroku logs').

You're going to need to post more information...